# Set IntPtr paramter default value to IntPtr.zero

Tags: c#, clr

How can I do this:

```
void Func(IntPtr p = IntPtr.Zero)
{
}
```

This is throwing an error:

> Default Parameter value of 'p' must be a compile-time constant.

Since somebody marked this as a duplicate question, the other question's answer are about setting it to "default" while I wanted it to be set to IntPtr.Zero.

Thank you

Comment: use the `default(IntPtr)`

Comment: Note that in the latest version of C# you can declare it like so: `public static void Func(IntPtr p = default)`

Comment: But Is default(IntPtr) same as setting to IntPtr.Zero ? how can i know that?

Comment: Yes, it's the same in this case.

Comment: How do you know its same?

Comment: @shaarang look at source code. `Zero` is basically a field with default value. https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IntPtr.cs,d46202ed9b6005b2,references

Comment: Because `(IntPtr.Zero == default)` is true.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, [7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#default-literal-expressions) is not [latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/) anymore.

Comment: @Sinatr OK, "recent" then. :) But it's still true that will work in the latest version!

Comment: @shaarang in this special case you _can_ know it: `default` fills the struct with zeros, which happen to be the same value as `IntPtr.Zero`. But in general you are right, it is merely an implementation detail, and this may not work for other structs/values.

Comment: In the source code : public static readonly IntPtr Zero;
Is this guaranteed to be Zero ?

Comment: The general case is to use `default` and then in the implementation use `if (value == default) value = theDefaultValueYouActuallyWant`, but this of course only works if `default` isn't something you actually want to use.